# Cookie Saves CartId always as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies

So cookie works but CartID is saved always as null while GuID is generated...probably i should add or change something in 3rd line.I am stacked please help. Here is the code :

```
    public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context )
    {

        if (context.Request.Cookies["CartId"] == null) return "0";

        string CartId = context.Request.Cookies["CartId"].Value;
        {               

            if (context.Request.Cookies["CartId"] == null)
             {

                CartId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CartId", CartId);

                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);


                context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                return CartId.ToString();
              }

            else   
            {

                return context.Request.Cookies["CartId"].Value;
            }



        }
```

Comment: I need GuId to be generated so that in db table every cart has a unique CartId...

Comment: Side note: Please when posting code for public viewing remove kindergarten level comments - there is absolutely no value in comments like `return cartId;// return cart id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some strange logic going on. Your second `if-statement` is doing the same check as the first. But in the first you already return, so the code never comes to the second.

I rewrote your code to follow this logic:

- If the cookie is not present, create a new id and store it in a cookie
- Return the newly created id or the id that was present in the cookie

In code:

```
public string GetCartId(HttpContextBase context )
{
    string cartId;
    if (context.Request.Cookies["CartId"] == null)
    {
        cartId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CartId", cartId);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    else 
    {
        cartId = context.Request.Cookies["CartId"].Value;
    }
    return cartId;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tested your code and again cartID is saved as null also.... I need a unique ID to be saved... so every client that runs a cart will see it's cart for 1 day long...

Comment: Right, so your request doesn't have a cookie yet. The the method always returns on the first statement. Updated my answer.

Comment: Correct. What is weird is that if i close browser and open it again it shows the cart... but what I want to make with a cookie is that every client remembers the cart by unique CartID... do you have any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If my answer solved your question but you have an additional question then you'd better create a new question. And accept my answer of course ;).

Comment: I suppose I did something wrong when I tied out your solution. Well I tested again your code and it works but not as persistent cookie. It does clears out  CartId after the set period of time... but when we close browser and open it again right after cookie dissapears. Sorry that I am writing after so much time but I tried many ways to find a solution and i saw that your solution works if only user won't close his browser... if you have any suggestions help me out  :)

Comment: Man you are awesome... it works and you made my day! In ie explorer cookie was working but on mozilla I used not saving history but allowing cookies... didn't think of that if history is not saved cookie is not saved either... I figoured it out when saw ie working... so I enabled history on mozilla and ... Boom!!! cartID was working !!! Thank's a lot. Have a good day a good month and a good luck :D

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpCookie c = request.cookies["getcookie"];
If (c == null)
{
c = New httpcookie("getcookie");
Guid g= guid.newguid().tostring();
c.value=g;
Response.cookies.add(c);
Return c.value;
}
else
{
return c.value;
}
```

Hope this is the code that you want please ignore the case sensitive cause I am typing from mobile.
Thank you.